# Is it feasible to manually draw from scratch a 2-layer PCB inside HFSS

Tags: pcb, rf, pcb-design, layout, balun

I am trying to replicate [a new planar marchand balun](http://www-ee.uta.edu/online/adavis/ee5349/wepi-1_balun.pdf#page=3)

Is it feasible to manually draw from scratch a 2-layer PCB inside HFSS ?

Or should I use external PCB drawing tool such as Kicad or Altium, then import the PCB layout into HFSS instead ?

Which method is easier to work with ?

[image: new planar marchand balun]

Comment: You can draw it in HFSS 3d Layout and export to HFSS

Comment: You can even analyze impedance in Saturn PCB and produce 0.12 gaps std at Sierra Proto Express (3mil track & gap)

Comment: You choose ENIG and copper weights variance to make a tolerance stack up with Polyamide PCB or Equiv

Comment: @Mike How is this different compared to exporting Kicad/Altium design file to HFSS ?

Comment: HFSS 3d Layout can handle and "understand" pcb geometry natively. You can draw (or edit after importing odb++) traces and place vias, name nets, etc.. similarly to pcb layout programs. You can then place ports on the layout components/elements and run the simulation using the HFSS engine to get s parameters. If you would like to view the fields I'd recommend exporting the project to HFSS after you are done with defining and refining the geometry/ports in HFSS 3d Layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can do either. If you build the geometry directly in HFSS it will be easier to adjust it, do parametric sweeps, etc., to optimize the design.

If you import from a CAD tool it will be easier to generate the manufacturing files when you're done.

One way: build and optimize the design in HFSS. Then rebuild it in CAD. Then import from CAD to HFSS to make sure you got the CAD design right.

Comment: As for manufacturing files, I assume gerber file. HFSS should be able generate gerber file on its own without external cad tool, I presume.

Comment: @Kevin, if it can, I'm not familiar with that function. HFSS can model many kinds of structures that can't be represented by gerbers, so be sure to check the gerber output carefully if you go that route.

Comment: Just a reference for others,  [edaboard link : PCB from hfss - creating gerber data out of hfss](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?145549-PCB-from-hfss-creating-gerber-data-out-of-hfss)